# How can I take the "printed" file path in Python, and use it in a Windows command line?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, tkinter

I am making a GUI where it allows you to:

1. Choose a file (user would click the first button, and a file browser pops up where user can navigate to desired file)

   Once selected, the "file path" of the file should be the output
2. Execute a batch file in the Windows command window (user would click second button, where the command window opens and uses the output from step 1)

   The input in the command window would be {MyFile.bat "the file path from step 1"} for example.

---

Where I am now?

I am able to output the file path but I can not get the file path into the Windows command prompt window, because instead of inputting the actual file path, it inputs the name of the output, rather than the actual output.

Example:

```
output name = x
after step 1, x should be = C\file\path\I\want.plz
```

after pressing the second button: The Windows command prompt opens and the line in the window writes: `MyFile.bat "x"` rather than `MyFile.bat "C\file\path\I\want.plz"`

---

```
def Button_Open_File(self):
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import filedialog

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    file_dir_name = print(**file_path**)
    
def Button_RUN_BATCH_FILE_ON_FILE_IN_CMD(self):
    import subprocess
    p1 = subprocess.check_call(**r'start cmd /c MyFile.bat "file_path"'**, shell=True, cwd="c:/Users/kimk4/Documents/")
    print('done')
```

I highlighted my problem areas with `**`, so as you can see, when I run this, I am able to print a file path in the Oython shell, but I am not able to get this batch file to work because instead of writing the actual path (in the window) to the file, it literally writes `file_path` rather than `c\file\location\that\user\navigates\to.thanks` in the Windows command prompt window.

Comment: It is writing the literal "file_path" because that is what you have coded. You need to concatenate the value of the file_path variable with the "start" string.

Comment: You can run `MyFile.bat` instead of `start cmd /c MyFile.bat`, but you should use the fully qualified path to the batch file to ensure it can be found. You don't need `shell=True` since Windows executes .bat and .cmd files using `cmd.exe /c`. If you need to attach to a new console window instead of inheriting the current console (if attached), then you can use `creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`.